# [PyQt4]QPushButton Focus Light

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

There is a QPushButton item in my app. And there are 2 screenshot from it. One of them is no-focused and the second one is focused.

[image: İmage1]
İmage 1

[image: image2]
İmage2 (When I focus it)

There is a highlight on the second image if you can recognize. When i focus this button with 'TAB', i can see this highlight.

I want to disable it. I'm using Python/PyQt4 and How can i disable this focus highlight? or Can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the highlighting on some elements maybe you want to disable the focus at all:

```
QWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to veto the event by overwriting it and then doing nothing.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal 
import os,sys 

class HoverButton(QtGui.QToolButton): 
    def enterEvent(self,event): 
        print("Enter") 
        #button.setStyleSheet("opacity:.5;") 

    def leaveEvent(self,evt): 
        print "LeaveEvent"
        #button.setStyleSheet("opacity:1;") 


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
button = HoverButton() 
button.show() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank You. But it doesn't work. Bcos, i can see the highlight when i use 'tab' or arrows.